# Linear spaces and linear transformation between them. Conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

$X,Y$ are linear spaces on the same field.  $\dim X=  7, \dim Y= 8, f:X\to Y$.   Then:
**a.** $f$ can be monomorphism
**b.** $f$ can be epiomorphism
**c.** $f$ can be isomorphism
**My approach:**
**a.** Yes, for example $f([a,b,c,d,e,f,g]) = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,a]$ is monomorphism.
**b.**  $\dim (im f)\le 7$.
**c.** Due to **c.** it can't be isomorphism.

Am I ok ?  Of course I look forward to see your explanations (my, seems to be poor).

Comment: Yes, well done.

Comment: Is it ok to say that **b.** is conclusion from rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Yes, sure; some more in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. More generally, let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces.

1. If $\dim V<\dim W$, then no linear map $f\colon V\to W$ can be surjective
2. If $\dim V=\dim W$, a linear map $f\colon V\to W$ is injective if and only if it is surjective (but can be neither)
3. If $\dim V>\dim W$, then no linear map $f\colon V\to W$ can be injective

All statements follow from the rank-nullity theorem.

For instance, suppose $\dim V<\dim W$; if $f\colon V\to W$ is linear, then $\dim\operatorname{im} f=\dim V-\dim\ker f<\dim W$, so $f$ is not surjective.

Moreover

1. If $\dim V\le\dim W$ then there exists an injective linear map $f\colon V\to W$
2. If $\dim V\ge\dim W$ then there exists a surjective linear map $f\colon V\to W$.

Hint for 1: let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$ be a basis for $W$; define $f$ such that $f(v_i)=w_i$, for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ (and extend by linearity).

Hint for 2: do similarly.

Comment: *but can be neither*.  What does it mean ? In case 2. we have **always**  isomorphism

Comment: @HaskellFun No, if $\dim V=\dim W$ a linear map $f\colon V\to W$ can be neither injective nor surjective, think to $f(v)=0$ for every $v\in V$; there *is* an isomorphism between $V$ and $W$, but not all linear maps $V\to W$ are isomorphisms.